# Adding ARAnchor at camera position, not World Origin

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

By default when adding an `ARAnchor` it is added at `World Origin` position. I am adding map anchors and these are updated when the location changes, the anchor is pushed out a certain distance and put on a bearing. If the distance is far the image is too small so its capped at 14 meters. If I continue walking towards the pin I can evently pass it because the position gets pushed out again from world origin. 
I have used code below to add pin at camera origin but it still seems to be at world origin, any idea why?

```
public class MapAnchor: ARAnchor {

    public var calloutString: String?
        public var distance: Float?
        public var location: CLLocation?
        public var originLocation: CLLocation?

        public convenience init(originLocation: CLLocation, location: CLLocation, pointOfView: SCNNode) {

            pointOfView.rotation = SCNVector4(0,0,0,0)
            let povTransform = pointOfView.simdWorldTransform


            let transform = povTransform.transformMatrix(originLocation: originLocation, location: location)
            self.init(transform: transform)

            self.distance = Float(location.distance(from: originLocation))
            self.location = location
            self.originLocation = originLocation
        }         
    }

    internal extension simd_float4x4 {

        func transformMatrix(originLocation: CLLocation, location: CLLocation) -> simd_float4x4 {
            // Determine the distance and bearing between the start and end locations
            let bearing = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(Float(originLocation.coordinate.direction(to: location.coordinate)))

            var distance = Float(location.distance(from: originLocation))
            distance = distance/10
            if(distance>14) {distance=14}
            //if(computedDistance<2) {computedDistance=2}
            let position = vector_float4(0.0, 0.0, -distance, 0.0)
            let translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4.translationMatrix(position)
            let rotationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4.rotationAroundY(radians: bearing)
            let transformMatrix = simd_mul(rotationMatrix, translationMatrix)
            return simd_mul(self, transformMatrix)
        }           
    }

    internal extension matrix_float4x4 {

        func rotationAroundY(radians: Float) -> matrix_float4x4 {
            var m : matrix_float4x4 = self;

            m.columns.0.x = cos(radians);
            m.columns.0.z = -sin(radians);

            m.columns.2.x = sin(radians);
            m.columns.2.z = cos(radians);

            return m.inverse;
        }

        func translationMatrix(_ translation : vector_float4) -> matrix_float4x4 {
            var m : matrix_float4x4 = self
            m.columns.3 = translation
            return m
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your *ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.worldAlignment* set to *.gravityAndHeading* ?

Comment: Yes it is .....

Comment: @tsukimi Did you find a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: @tsukimi did you find an answer for this?